# Complexity of a reaching-a-node 2 player graph game

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

The game:

- There is an undirected simple graph with some special, winning nodes, and 2 players, who take turns.
- Player one (Seeker) moves on the graph (sits on a node, and moves along an edge), and tries to reach a winning node. If she reaches one, she wins. Her initial position is given at the start.
- Player two (Eraser) can turn the winning nodes into regular nodes. She wins, if the other player can't win, that is, she erased all the winning nodes into regular ones.

I am interested about this game.

E.g. if this game "can be solved" in polynomial or even in NP or coNP time, that is, whether it is possible to decide who has a winning strategy. Or whether this game is in the literature, and is known to be easy or hard, possibly in a different form.

Thank you!

Comment: Also posted on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70305834/complexity-of-a-reaching-a-node-2-player-graph-game

Comment: I recommend including the example you gave over on SO, by editing it into your question here. It reveals some of the complexity of the game.